# Achieve the horizontal scroll in fixed div

Tags: html, css

I want to display internal div inline and horizontally scroll-able when my outer div have fixed height and width.

HTML:

```
<!-- fixed height and width -->
<div class="outer"> 
   <!-- inner dives which will display horizontally scrolled -->
   <div class="inner"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
    max-width:100; 
    height:60px; 
    border: 1px thin #333;
}

.outer {
   width: 300px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   height: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have .inner with a max-width of `100` with no units. I'm assuming `px`? If so, then you want things to scroll horizontally with no wrapping at all? If so, this should do what you want:

```
.inner
{
    display: inline-block; /* makes your divs side-by-side */
    max-width:100px;
    height:60px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.outer {
    white-space: nowrap; /* makes all your inner divs stay on the same line */
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 320px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zzqhcvof/